# How to retrieve validators elected for a new Era?

Tags: pallet-election-phragmen

Does anyone know how to retrieve validators elected for the new era ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

> Through the runtime call grandpaApi -> grandpaAuthorities() which queries the current state of the authority set.

Returns the authority session keys associated with grandpa, as described [here](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-cryptography#session-keys).

If you want to know the validator stash accounts associated with staking, you can use:

- [`Session::Validators`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_session/pallet/storage_types/struct.Validators.html): current validators.
- [`Session::QueuedKeys`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_session/pallet/storage_types/struct.QueuedKeys.html): set of next validators.

Answer (score 0):

Through the runtime call [grandpaApi -> grandpaAuthorities()](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/runtime/) which queries [the current state of the authority set](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3a94009daac8919db46e3014964fe23866edb996/frame/grandpa/src/lib.rs#L294-L298).